# Stop disk activity of a process without killing the process

Tags: windows, hard-drive, process, io

Is there a technique or tool that can be used to stop a running process from writing to a drive, but not kill the process.

If I have more level of control in that, like selecting which drives the process can write, and only allow reads on some drive etc. would be nicer.

The use case is that I have a process that once I get it running seems to be trashing the disk and since it is single threaded its UI freezes up during this time. I need it to stop trashing the drive (C:) but still be able to export some results from it, at the end of it.

I'm would be happy with a programmatic way as well.
The OS would be `Win7` if that makes a difference.

Comment: What does the process _do_ with that I/O? Is it even slightly related to the results that you're exporting, or is it some completely unrelated feature that you would disable if you could? (What I'm getting at is, assuming the process _will_ issue those requests, how will it react to them being denied?)

Comment: @user1686 basically when I start the process all seems fine, and I tell the process to generate some data for me, the process generates the data and shows it to be in the GUI but during this time it also starts  disk thrashing and and there is no way for me to access the results.

Comment: It needs to read the disk to process the data, and it occasionally writes to disk some state data, but I don't think denying it write access will cause any major issues. Of course after the data is generated , I need to export it to another drive letter, so hopefully if I can deny the process by drive letter it would be nice.

Comment: Run it as a user that only have read access?

Comment: @NiKiZe  seems a good idea or at least this I get a better solution, will try it out

Comment: Did you already indentify that process? What's its **name**? Please, add to that info your post. Did you already check out the **disk health** with some software like, for example, [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/)?

Comment: @JorgeLuiz its a custom process that I wrote, however currently I don't have the resources (time) to debug it and identify the cause of disk trashing. So looking for a quick fix here. The thrashing occurs intermittently so I'm not so worried about it, but I need the process to work at certain times, and it should not fail me then. Not checked disk health as yet, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Anchovy Did you try to run the process **as a specific user** which doesn't have access to that **specific disk**? [You could use the command **runas** for doing that task.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))

Comment: @JorgeLuiz no haven't done that yet, was trying to process the information given above in the comments, NiKiZe suggested on the same lines earlier, thanks  for the further comments, will check it out

Comment: You can use normal resource manager to see what is accessing disk, one possibility is swap.

Comment: @NiKiZe yes I know the process which is accessing the disk, but I need a way to block it writing to the disk. I guess I can use your idea of loggin in with another user and running the program with read access

Comment: We, if it is swap, then you will not be able to block it.